# Flutter - Pop until a screen without route

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I have a Flutter app that starts like this :

```
void main() async {

  // Check if user is logged in

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: (isLoggedIn) ? MainPage() : PageLogin(),
    ),
  );
}
```

My MainPage (and my LoginPage) are just 2 regular Stateful Widgets.

```
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainPage({Key key, this.selectedPageDefault = 0}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}
```

Let's say I have 2 more pages, just like MainPage : `PageOne` and `PageTwo`.
When I click on a button on `MainPage`, it takes me to `PageOne`, and when I click on a button on `PageOne`, it takes me to `PageTwo`.
I go to them using :

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => PageOne(), // Or PageTwo
  ),
);
```

Now, when I click on a button in `PageTwo`, I want to go back to `MainPage`.
I could use `Navigator.of(context).popUntil(...)`, however it needs to use routes, and I did not go to `MainPage` using a route.

This is just an example, but on the real app I have more than just 2 pages after `MainPage`, so I can't just use `pushReplacement` or a tricky way to achieve this.

How can I go back to `MainPage` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this `Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst)`

Answer (score 7):

You need to add settings like this

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => MainPage(),
    settings : RouteSettings()..name = 'MainPage',
  ),
);
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => PageOne(),
    settings : RouteSettings()..name = 'PageOne',
  ),
);
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => PageTwo(),
    settings : RouteSettings()..name = 'PageTwo',
  ),
);
```

and you can use this

```
 Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName('MainPage'));
```

Comment: Could you please show me how to use them in my `main()` function ? Should I set a Navigator function instead of my Page in the `home` property of `MaterialApp` ?

Comment: @Elynad If your page definitely first stack, you can use this 'Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst)'

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you @Taz !  
Write your comment as an answer and I will mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: use RouteSettings(name:'PageTwo' ) instead of RouteSettings()..name = 'PageTwo' as name is final variable

Comment: what if i want to go specific pop screen not first , because above solution not working for specific screen also isFirst not working   , so any idea?

Comment: name is now final. Use:  RouteSettings(name:  "routename"),